# Need help interpreting/converting math formula for javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a math formula that I need to convert to Javascript readable format.

```
 const result = (100 × w) / (52.2 + (41.9 × e-0.055 × r))
```

I have no problem with most of it. The part that is holding me up is 
     e-0.055

I am assuming that it's referring to Euler's number but am unsure how to get it to work.

I tried:

```
 const result = (100 * w) / (52.2 + (41.9 * Math.E(-0.055 * r)));
```

but that throws an error.

Another form of the same formula written for some server side language is:
     1 RM = {:frac{100* "w" }{52.2+41.9*e^{-0.055* "r" }}:}

but again, the "e^" part eludes me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the exponentiation operator `**` to raise `E` to the `(-0.055 * r)` power?

```
 const result = (100 * w) / (52.2 + (41.9 * Math.E**(-0.055 * r)));
```

also there is `Math.pow` available if you aren't using es6+

```
const result = (100 * w) / (52.2 + (41.9 * Math.pow(Math.E,(-0.055 * r))));
```

and interestingly enough there is also a combined function `Math.exp` which raise `E` to `x`

```
const result = (100 * w) / (52.2 + (41.9 * Math.exp(-0.055 * r)));
```

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thanks. So I was just missing the "**" which I have never seen before. I notice that it's a "new" operator in ES6, denoting exponentiation. So I just needed to replace the ^ (which does the same job in non javascript functions) with the ** ES6 equivalent.

Comment: @KelvinAitken ah good point, I updated in case you need something below es6!

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. I was aware of Math.pow but was having trouble figuring out how it all went together. I will stick with the ES6 as I live under the blissful assumption that IE is dead and everyone uses a recent browser.

Answer (score 0):

**EULER FORMULA**

> **Euler formula**, named after Leonhard Euler, is a mathematical formula of the specific area of ​​complex analysis, which shows a relation between trigonometric functions and exponential function (Euler identity is a special case of Euler's formula ). **The formula is given by:**

[euler formula image](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_e.asp)

**AT WHERE**

> `x` is the real argument (in radians);
>
> `e` is the basis of the natural logarithm;
>
> `i² = -1`, where `i` is the imaginary unit (complex number)

You are correct, `e-0.055` is what you imagined, so knowing this as its formula is static, you can use the following:

> a) **e-0.055** = 2.66328182846
>
> b) JavaScript `E` Property

**JAVASCRIPT** `E` **PROPERTY**

> The `E` property returns the Euler's number and the base of natural logarithms, approximately 2.718.

**EXAMPLE:**

```html
<p>Click the button to display Euler's number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.E;
}
</script>
```

Complementing, you can use what **@Asleepace** answered you which is correct according to your scenario:

```
const result = (100 * w) / (52.2 + (41.9 * Math.E**(-0.055 * r)));
```

[OFFICIAL SOURCE - W3SCHOOLS: JAVASCRIPT E PROPERTY](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_e.asp)

[OFFICIAL SOURCE - WIKIPEDIA: EULER FORMULA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Euler)